# Filter or select on data.table causes new data.table to come up empty with correct columns but no rows

Tags: r, data.table, t-test

The data for this question can be found here:

Here is the original data:
https://github.com/cjy8s/data/blob/c9605876625b3aec8acb949c8bb0b6b4be3a8c41/tab_cond_Loc_phases.csv

Here is the t.test data, which is the data available right before problems occur
https://github.com/cjy8s/data/blob/e8e79fdc62d3d8b36a9fd842c0b0dcfa731ec2e1/ttest_compList_2.csv

So I am trying to perform t.tests on the conditions found in the data.table `tab_cond_Loc_phases`. In my current dataset, I have 82 experimental conditions or about 3300 comparison pairs when I use `combn`. The t.tests work great, and I store those values in a data.table called `ttest_compList_2`. I am able to add a few extra columns successfully, but when I try to select/filter only the rows with values < 0.5 in the column `p_value`, the new data.table (named `ttest_compList` for problem-solving sake) comes up with no rows but no error message.

If I use `select` instead of `filter`, then I get this error:

```
Error in `select()`:
! Problem while evaluating `p_value < 0.05`.
Caused by error:
! object 'p_value' not found
```

This doesn't seem to happen when I use a dataset for `tab_cond_Loc_phases` that has fewer conditions to compare. I'm not sure why my code is unable to see the `p_value` column of `tab_cond_Loc_phases` here.

I'm also sure there is probably a better way to do my t.tests, but this has worked so far. I am also interested to hear if anyone has feedback on my general approach here as well if they are willing to give it.

Here is my MRE:

```
controls <- c("WT+DMSO", "MUT+DMSO")

#Get the unique names of the rows in a column
condition_vec <- unique(tab_cond_Loc_phases$condition)

#get a list of all possible combinations of conditions, without duplication or replicates
col_vec <- combn(condition_vec, 2, FUN = paste)

#for combinations of condition averages to be compared with t.tests over time, grouped by condition
con_tab_2 <- list()

for (comparison in 1:ncol(col_vec)) {
  #Loop through the col_vec combinations and use each pairing as arguments for t.test comparisons
  tmp_ttest_2 <- t.test(tab_cond_Loc_phases[condition == col_vec[1, comparison], exp_sums],
                       tab_cond_Loc_phases[condition == col_vec[2, comparison], exp_sums])

  #Additional columns describing the t.tests, to be added to a data.table.
  #Each value of res_tab_2 represents one t.test comparison
  res_tab_2 <- data.table(
    condition1 = combn(condition_vec, 2)[1, comparison],
    condition2 = combn(condition_vec, 2)[2, comparison],
    t_statistic = tmp_ttest_2$statistic,
    df = tmp_ttest_2$parameter,
    p_value = tmp_ttest_2$p.value,
    mean_cond1 = tmp_ttest_2$estimate[1],
    mean_cond2 = tmp_ttest_2$estimate[2],
    method = tmp_ttest_2$method
  )
  
  #Add the row of t.test data from res_tab_2 from the current iteration to the growing list of lists
  #These will be added together to make one data.table
  con_tab_2[[comparison]] <- rbind(res_tab_2)
  print(paste('t.test comparison group ', comparison, '/', ncol(col_vec)))
}

#Bind all of the lists within con_tab_2 together to make one data.table, for easier referencing later
ttest_compList_2 <- rbindlist(con_tab_2)

#This filters the comparisons that contain at least one of the controls and only keeps the statistically significant comparisons
ttest_compList <- ttest_compList_2 %>%
  mutate(pair = as.numeric(factor(1:nrow(ttest_compList_2))),
         xmin = pair - 0.2,
         xmax = pair + 0.2) %>%
  dplyr::filter(p_value < 0.05, grepl(paste(controls, collapse = "|"), condition1) | grepl(paste(controls, collapse = "|"), condition2))
```

**UPDATE**
For anyone that may be interested, I made a faster way to do the t.tests because of r2evans comment. On my computer, the previous way, updated with theN's answer, executes in about 33 seconds. This new way executes in about 12 seconds.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

###Maybe think about changing the t.test format to be better.... more like the otherone so that 
#you don't need rbind and rbindlist
#get subsets of the data instead of just one row of the data at a time

controls <- c("WT+DMSO", "MUT+DMSO")

#Get the unique names of the rows in a column
condition_vec <- unique(tab_cond_Loc_phases$condition)

# Create an empty data.table to store the results
ttest_results <- data.table()

#See how many times each condition occurs, so that you don't get errors if any condition appears only once
occurances <- tab_cond_Loc_phases[, list(replicates = .N), by = condition]

#allow the ttests if there are more than 1 replicate of each condition
if(min(occurances[['replicates']]) > 1) {
  #get a list of all possible combinations of conditions, without duplication or replicates
  col_vec <- combn(condition_vec, 2, simplify = FALSE)
  col_vec_length <- length(col_vec)
  
  for (i in 1:col_vec_length) {
    
    #Selecting conditions to be t.tested
    condition1 <- col_vec[[i]][1]
    condition2 <- col_vec[[i]][2]
    
    #subset the data for the current condition combinations
    conds_subset1 <- tab_cond_Loc_phases[condition == condition1, exp_sums]
    conds_subset2 <- tab_cond_Loc_phases[condition == condition2, exp_sums]
    
    # Perform the t-test
    ttest <- t.test(conds_subset1, conds_subset2)
    
    # Store the results in the data.table
    ttest_results <- rbind(ttest_results, data.table(condition1 = condition1, 
                                                     condition2 = condition2,
                                                     mean_condition1 = ttest$estimate[1],
                                                     mean_condition2 = ttest$estimate[2],
                                                     statistic = ttest$statistic,
                                                     df = ttest$parameter,
                                                     p.value = ttest$p.value,
                                                     method = ttest$method))
   
  }
}

#This filters the comparisons that contain at least one of the controls and only keeps the statistically significant comparisons
ttest_results <- ttest_results %>%
  mutate(pair = as.numeric(factor(1:nrow(ttest_results))),
         xmin = pair - 0.2,
         xmax = pair + 0.2) %>%
  filter(p.value < 0.05, condition1 %in% controls | condition2 %in% controls)
```

Comment: (1) `'controls' not found`. (2) Why the `rbind` in `rbind(res_tab_2)`? It's already a frame (`data.table`), it seems not useful to `rbind` a single frame. (3) Using `c` as a variable name is frowned upon, it's visually confusing even if R usually knows which to use. (4) This is a lot to process; even if I did have `control`, it's take a bit of time to get here. I suggest you reduce the problem significantly and provide sample data at the point immediately before where you are having problems.

Comment: OK I added some explanations for my thought processes as comments, including why I had `rbind`. I added `controls`, which I had forgotten to include from the rest of my code. I tried to make this MRE more concise, and also changed the variable name in the for loop. Hopefully that is better. Currently, it seems like my code is not able to see the `p_value` column from `ttest_compList_2` and I'm not sure why...

Comment: That's a lot of data and a lot of code, did something prevent you from minimising the logic and the data ?

Comment: I explain in the question itself that the problem doesn't occur when I work with simpler data, especially with data that has fewer conditions. For that reason, I chose to work with a more realistic replica of the real data so that others could replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my observation, it seems that the error is with the matching using `grepl()`.

I am not very proficient with regex, so I am suggesting a slightly different approach using `%in%`.

```
ttest_compList <- ttest_compList_2 %>%
  mutate(pair = as.numeric(factor(1:nrow(ttest_compList_2))),
         xmin = pair - 0.2,
         xmax = pair + 0.2) %>%
  dplyr::filter(p_value < 0.05, condition1 %in% controls | condition2 %in% controls)
```

I changed the last chunk of code as shown above, this should work.